# Will iWork '08 support autosave and versions?

Tags: macos, iwork

Will iWork '08 work support autosave and versions? I really only use iWork like twice a year, and don't feel like buying a new one.

EDIT: Wait! It supports app resume though! Yay! Does all app support app resume by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe iWork '08 will support those features.

Comment: +1. Apple is very bad about updating older versions of anything.

Comment: Damn... Ok then I guess I'll live without autosave for iWork for a while.. TextEdit will do for now.